# Code that behaves like response.redirect in express in loopback4?

Tags: express, loopbackjs, loopback

I'm newbie in loopback4.
I am developing code to get Google access token.
how do I implement features like Express's redirect?

I have already succeeded in implementing it with express.
Now I want to implement it as a unique feature of loopback4.

Express based code(already working)

```
router.get('/googleiab/token/request', function (req, res) {
    let oauth2Client = new OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri);
    let url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: scopes,
    });
    res.redirect(url);
});
```

Loopback 4

```
@get('/googleiab/token/request')
  tockenRequest(): void {
    let oauth2Client = new OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri);
    let url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline',
      scope: scopes,
    });
    this.redirect('/googleiab/token/request', url, 301); //res.redirect(url);
    //return url;
  }
```

This will redirect to the specified Url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use RequestContext for this purpose.

See below.

Add this injection into constructor

```
@inject(RestBindings.Http.CONTEXT)
protected reqContext: RequestContext
```

Then do this in your tockenRequest method.

```
@get('/googleiab/token/request')
  tockenRequest(): void {
    let oauth2Client = new OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri);
    let url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline',
      scope: scopes,
    });
    this.reqContext.response.redirect(url);
  }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Glad I could help.